# SCCM 2012 R2: Email / Alert on component status errors

Tags: configuration-management, sccm, system-center

I know that as of SCCM SP1 we are now able to monitor and alert on a few more things in SCCM.  We can now alert if there are problems with not only AV / malware alerts but also client and database problems.  However, it doesn't seem like there is the ability to monitor if a component (Monitoring > System Status > Component Status) is showing in a critical state.  All of the alerts that I can see under 'All Alerts' are Endpoint Protection alerts, client health alerts, site server alerts (deployments, db rep, db drive, sideloading win 8) and site system alerts (SUP, MP).

How can I email alerts when a site system status or a component status records an error message?  When SMS_STATUS_MANAGER or say SMS_MP_CONTROL_MANAGER have an error I want to know;  I don't want to have to come to the site and leave a RDP session open to monitor this.